# question about python GUI

Tags: python, user-interface

So I am taking a digital image processing class that requires implementing some image filters, reconstruction, enhancements. I plan to use python for it but my professor wants to have a simple GUI with two canvas for pre- and post-processing images, a drop down box for filter selection, some textboxes for filter value/thresholds and stuff. I have the following questions to ask:

1. Is it possible to load image to a canvas in python GUI library?
2. Does the advantage from coding out-weight the disadvantages of having to code the GUI manually?
3. Given the requirements, what would be the best and easiest library to use? I choose python since it reduces implementation time, but if the GUI turns out to be a bummer I would rather use Java.
4. If the answer for the 3 previous questions are YES, please point me in the right direction with some documents.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend writing the processing code separately, then writing a GUI wrapper around it.

There are [many choices](http://wiki.python.org/moin/GuiProgramming), however I'd consider the big three below:

- [Tkinter](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TkInter), in the standard install, simple but a bit clunky.
- [wxPython](http://www.wxpython.org/), a better choice, higher quality but a bit more complicated.  Uses native widgets.
- [PyQT](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PyQt), many love this toolkit and its documentation.  I have only limited expertise with it.  Uses custom drawn widgets.

Comment: wxPython is a great recommendation :)

Answer (score -1):

Look at [Phatch](http://photobatch.stani.be/). It is a Python Photo Batch Processor with a nice graphical user interface. It is based on [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) imaging library which you'll probably want to use.

Comment: We are not allowed to use any library except for one that open a photo in a canvas. I am not looking for a software.